# Want To Use Two One-To-Many Associations To Update The Same Model - Rails 3.2.9 - Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, model-associations

I have read some of the other Stack Overflow questions that were submitted where you had two Models belonging to a single Model but I could not find one that addressed my specific issue.

I have a User model, a Message model and a Response Model.

The User model has_many messages and has_many responses.  Both have dependent destroy options.

The Message model belongs_to user and has_many responses.  The message model has user_id which ties back to the User model.  It has dependent destroy for responses.

The Response model belongs_to message and belongs_to user.  The response model has message_id which ties back to the message model and user_id which I would like to also tie back to the user model.

Without regard for the User model I know with the response model I could do something like message.responses.build to create a new response with the message_id populated from the message it is related to.  However if I consider the user_id I currently have it is not automatically populated.  I also understand that if I was the message id I can do response. message to get that row.

I hope to be able to automatically delete all responses for a deleted message or a deleted user.   What I would like to do is to do a single command similar to message.responses.build where it would know to update both message_id and user_id on my response row.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can add `user_id` as option for `build` method

Comment: Thanks so much for your input.  Would I do something like message.responses.build(attributes={:user_id, :message_id}) to update message_id to the id of the message and the user_id to the current user creating the record?  I have not used the build method with arguments before.

Comment: I mean `message.responses.build :user_id => user.id`